# drawableRight close to the text when width match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I have a `radiobutton` with text and a picture on the right, I want the `width` to be the `parent_width`, but `drawableright` is close to the text on the right. How can I achieve this?
I get the following
[image]

I want to get the following but full screen clickable in `width` 
[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
            tools:text="Test"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please paste your layout here this information is not enough...

Comment: @MahendraGohil pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply end (right) padding to the `RadioButton` that will shift the drawable to the left. The question is how much padding should be applied? Since the amount of padding will change depending upon several factors, the calculation will have to be done in code. (If you have a well-defined environment and know that text length won't change, you could just set the padding in the XML.)

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RadioButton mRadioButton;
    private RadioButton mRadioButton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        mRadioButton2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

        RadioGroup rg = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        rg.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                moveDrawable(mRadioButton);
                moveDrawable(mRadioButton2);
            }

            private void moveDrawable(RadioButton radioButton) {
                // Get the drawables for this radio button. If the right drawable is not null
                // then we need to move it to the end of the text.
                Drawable[] drawables = radioButton.getCompoundDrawables();
                if (drawables[2] != null) {
                    // Compute how much end padding to apply to get the drawable beside the text.
                    int textLen = (int) radioButton.getPaint().measureText((String) radioButton.getText());
                    // 4dp between the text and the drawable just to separate them a little.
                    int drawableLeftPadding =
                        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                                                        4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    int paddingEnd = radioButton.getWidth() -
                        (radioButton.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + +textLen + drawables[2].getIntrinsicWidth())
                        - drawableLeftPadding;
                    radioButton.setPadding(0, 0, paddingEnd, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_insert_emoticon_yellow_24dp"
            android:text="Test Test Test Test Test " />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_insert_emoticon_yellow_24dp"
            android:text="Test" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_insert_emoticon_yellow_24dp"
            android:text="Test" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! though I wanted a solution using only xml, but it will do too

Comment: @Nikitc No XML-only solution that I am aware of unless you want to restrict yourself to things that can be represented textually such as emojis. <string name="emoji">Test&#x1F600;</string> will give you text with a grinning face at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like your parent container for `RadioButton` is having width "`match_parent`"

**Make your parent container width** "`wrap_content`" or **replace your snippet with given one as below**.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"    //the only change is here
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            tools:text="Test"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no, I just want the arrow next to the text, but the radiobutton itself is the full width. Thanks

Comment: check the ans now

Comment: this did not give the result, the parent container in any case should be stretched to the full width, the child should also be the full width, but the icon should be next to the text and not far from it